# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: myFunction.watch is not a function

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, javascript, truffle-contract

I'm trying to develop my first DAPP based on this tutorial (https://livebook.manning.com/book/building-ethereum-dapps/chapter-12/) and I'm encountering some errors in the javascript part. In particular, when declaring the following:

```
SimpleVoting.deployed()
.then(instance => instance.VoterRegisteredEvent())
.then(voterRegisteredEventSubscription => {
    voterRegisteredEvent = voterRegisteredEventSubscription;    
        voterRegisteredEvent.watch(function(error, result) {
      if (!error)
        $("#voterRegistrationMessage").html('Voter successfully registered');
      else
        console.log(error);
    });           
});
```

I get the error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: voterRegisteredEvent.watch is not a function

It seems that the tutorial I'm following is outdated. What is the current method to listen for an event like above?

Comment: do a console.log of voterRegisteredEventSubscription on the 4th line and see what the structure of the object is

Comment: it's an EventEmitter. The structure is 
EventEmitter {_events: {…}, _maxListeners: undefined}
_events:
[[Prototype]]: Object
_maxListeners: undefined
[[Prototype]]: Object
addListener: ƒ (type, listener)
emit: ƒ (type)
listenerCount: ƒ (type)
listeners: ƒ (type)
on: ƒ (type, listener)
once: ƒ (type, listener)
removeAllListeners: ƒ (type)
removeListener: ƒ (type, listener)
setMaxListeners: ƒ (n)
_events: undefined
_maxListeners: undefined
constructor: ƒ EventEmitter()
[[Prototype]]: Object

Comment: @Sandruz You are using truffle so instance is an instance of Truffle's contract. If you want to use web3 events you have to use `instance.contract` instead.